# How to tell Xcode to attach debugger to a process as soon as the process will start?

Tags: xcode, debugging, application-restart

I'm working on something that happens just when my app restarts, and I'm trying to get logs for that. So I build my app, kill it, and restart it.

Killing the app makes Xcode disconnect from the running process.

After I restart the app, I can select `Debug > Attach to Process` to attach Xcode to the new process, but I'll miss everything that happens between the app start and when I manually attach to the process.

Is there a way to tell Xcode `there no process running currently, but as soon as process X starts, attach the debugger to it`?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Attach to process by PID or Name` feature.

It's under the `Debug -> Attach to process by PID or Name` menu in Xcode, then simply type in the process name that you normally attach to, and select `Attach`.

Once your app with said `PID` or `name` starts up, the debugger will attach to it immediately.

Make sure to set breakpoints for as early as late as you want to catch the launch.

Comment: This answer describes a manual process, the question seems to be looking for an automatic way